# PyMongo connections not being released: Error as no more connections to MongoDB available

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a script which uses up all available connections of the locally running MongoDB and then exists with this error message:

```
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

The error message in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log is:

```
[initandlisten] connection refused because too many open connections: 819
```

The Mongo-Shell gives this output when the script is being invoked:

```
> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 1, "available" : 818 }  // Script not yet started
> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 400, "available" : 419 }  // Losing connections
> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 638, "available" : 181 }
> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 804, "available" : 15 }
> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 819, "available" : 0 }  // Script terminates
> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 1, "available" : 818 }  // Script terminated
```

I am not able to post the original script, but the following "sanitized" snippet hopefully gives an idea. Basically, I am running all sorts of different queries and updates across several collections.

Most importantly only 5 of 11 database statements will *sometimes* not release their connection. The other 6 statements will *always* leave as many free connections as there were before the statement.

```
mc = pymongo.Connection()
db = mc.database

def available():
    """ Return the number of available connections """
    return db.command("serverStatus")['connections']['available']

def process():
    while True:
        # ...
        # Connections lost:
        conns = available()
        coll_a = db.coll_a.find_and_modify(
                query={'x': x},
                update={'$pop': {'x': -1}},
                fields={'x': 1})
        if conns > available():
            print('Fewer connections')
        # ...
        # No connections lost:
        db.coll_a.update({'x': x}, {'$pullAll': {'x': [x]}})
        # ...
        # No connections lost:
        coll_d = db.coll_d.find_and_modify(
                query={'x': x,},
                update={'$set': {'x': x}},
                fields={'x': 1})
        # ...
        # No connections lost:
        coll_b_cursor = db.coll_b.find({'x': x}, {'x': 1})
        # ...
        # No connections lost:
        coll_e_cursor = db.coll_e.find({'$or': [{'x': x}, {'x': x}]})
        # ...
        for item in coll_e_cursor:
            # No connections lost:
            coll_b = db.coll_b.find({'x': x}).count()
        # ...
        # No connections lost:
        coll_b_cursor = db.coll_b.find({'x': x}, {'x': x})
        # ...
        for x in y:
            if x:
                # Connections lost:
                conns = available()
                db.coll_b.update({'x': x}, {'$unset': {'x': 1}})
                if conns > available():
                    print('Fewer connections')
            # ...
            # Connections lost:
            conns = available()
            coll_b = db.coll_b.find_and_modify(
                    query={'x': x},
                    update={'$set': {'x': x}},
                    fields={'x': 1},
                    upsert=True)
            if conns > available():
                print('Fewer connections')
            # ...
            # Connections lost:
            conns = available()
            coll_c_1 = db.coll_c.find_one({'x': x})
            coll_c_2 = db.coll_c.find_one({'x': x})
            if conns > available():
                print('Fewer connections')
        # ...
        # Connections lost:
        conns = available()
        db.coll_b.update({'x': x}, {'$unset': {'x': 1}})
        if conns > available():
            print('Fewer connections')
```

- What is the difference between the statements that do not release their connections and those that do?
- Should PyMongo or MongoDB not free connections under all circumstances?

PyMongo: 2.2.1

MongoDB: 2.0.6

Comment: What does your `pymongo.Connection` call look like?

Comment: Try changing that to `pymongo.Connection(safe=True)`.  I think your write operations are getting so far ahead of the database that you're consuming loads of connections.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not fix the issue. Nevertheless, thank you!

Comment: I ran the script as you have it and my number of connections stayed constant.  Are you sure there isn't something else running that's taking connections?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It is the only script that is running. Maybe the problem only arises in combination with my specific data or the amount of data that is being processed.

Comment: I noticed that the 5 problematic statements only sometimes do not release their connections. While the other 6 statements always do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connections were not lost *where* it seemed but *when*.

I overlooked a thread was started somewhere in process():

```
threading.Thread(target=target, args=(args)).start()
```

This thread made a database call.

The while loop in process() was fast enough so that many threads were running simultaneously. Using up all available database connections.

Without launching these threads, the number of available database connections remains constant.